# ios: TableViewControl in TabViewControl the navigation bar overlaps table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

The root View View controller is Navigation controller and its first level is a TabViewController.One of the tab item is a TableViewController.
Here is the relationship:
[image]

However the navigation bar overlap the table view:
[image]

I have also set simulated metrics,So what can be the problem??

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Simulated metrics are just that, simulated. They do not actually apply to the compiled product.

To fix this, I find it easiest to set the `edgesforextendedlayout` with the various values of [edge values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout). Usually all but the top.

Answer (score 0):

The `rootViewController` should be the `UITabBarController`. Follow this code:

1.Make the `UITabBarController` the `rootViewController` in the application delegate or in your `main.storyboard`  set it as the `initial View Controller`.

2.In the `UITabBarController`.m place this code there to create the `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` embeded inside of it.

```
//Inside UITabBarController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];


    self.viewControllers = @[navCon];

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know why I got the navigation overlap the table view?

Comment: @AndrewCarl Did you check your `autoresizingMask` property?

Comment: I don't set this property manually and should I set it to some Value?

Comment: @AndrewCarl Your problem is that you are using a `UITableViewController`. Change that to a `UIViewController` and place a `UITableView` inside of it. Then place all your `UITableView` Delegate methods inside your `UIViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the navigation controller in the beginning and, instead, embed the tableviewcontroller inside a navigation controller.

**(Select the view controller -- Click "editor" > "embed in" > "navigation controller").**

Make sure the tab bar controller is the root view controller as well

**This will also fix the overlapping issue**

Comment: This acctually does fix the issure,Thanks but could you tell me why the before scene would lead to the overlaping?

Comment: @AndrewCarl i don't exactly have an explanation as I am a beginner, but I just I see it as the way things work in Xcode. I'm honestly still learning the ropes lol.